# How to select the first value in every group

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> create table t1(id int,level int,gap int);
mysql> insert into t1 values (1,6,50),(1,5,10),(2,5,10),(2,5,12),(3,8,10),
(3,8,2),(3,9,6),(3,9,4);
```

This two commands can create a table like following

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+-------+------+
| id   | level | gap  |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     6 |   50 |
|    1 |     5 |   10 |
|    2 |     5 |   10 |
|    2 |     5 |   12 |
|    3 |     8 |   10 |
|    3 |     8 |    2 |
|    3 |     9 |    6 |
|    3 |     9 |    4 |
+------+-------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to select **one record** when the `level` is maximal but the gap is minimal in every `group by id`.So I think this code should work for me

```
mysql> select id,max(level),first(gap) from (select * from t1 group by id,
level,gap) as tem group by id;
```

But I find the mysql have no `first` function.This is current solution.

```
select
  tt.id,tt.level,min(tt.gap) min_gap 
from (
  select * from t1 tt1
    where not exists(
      select 1 from t1 tt2 where tt1.id=tt2.id and tt1.level<tt2.level
    )
  ) tt
group by tt.id,tt.level;
```

It will give a **right answer** like

[image]

But is there any concise method can solve this question?

Comment: What if max level record and min gap in one group is not the same record? Or you just want to query the max level and min gap in each group?

Comment: Please format your queries that we do not have to scroll and they are way more easy to read

Comment: @Forward,inetphantom I have updated it.

Comment: @RandomSeed Thanks for your link.But actually I prefer to know how te refine my `first` version.